# How to Upload File from .net core client to .net core API? I Trying to consume this API from .Net client but There is time out exception or Badrequest

Tags: .net, api, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

API Method

```
    [Route("~/api/[controller]/FileUpload")]
    public IActionResult FileUpload([FromForm] UploadModel UserId)
    {
        var userid = "*****";
        var pass = "******";
        try
        {
            using (FtpClient ftp = CreateFTPClient(userid, pass))
            {
                if (DoesFtpDirectoryExist("ftp://localhost:21" + "/" + UserId.UserId, userid, pass))
                {
                    if (CheckIfFileExistsOnServer(UserId.UserId,UserId.file.FileName ,userid, pass))
                    {
                        
                        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(UserId.file.FileName) ;
                        string fname = fi.Name.Remove((fi.Name.Length - fi.Extension.Length));
                        fname = fname + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("_ddMMyyhhmmss") + fi.Extension;
                        var status = Upload(UserId.file.OpenReadStream(), UserId.UserId, userid, pass,fname);
                        return Ok("File already Exist... Please note renamed file name for your reference."+status+"");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var stream = UserId.file.OpenReadStream();
                        var status = Upload(stream, UserId.UserId, userid, pass, UserId.file.FileName);
                        return Ok(status);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("ftp://localhost:21" + "/" + UserId.UserId);
                    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
                    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userid, pass);
                    using (var resp = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                    {
                        var stream = UserId.file.OpenReadStream();
                        var nameandext = UserId.file.FileName;
                        FtpWebRequest reqObj = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://localhost:21" + "/" + UserId.UserId + "/" + nameandext);
                        var status = Upload(stream, UserId.UserId, userid, pass, UserId.file.FileName);
                        return Ok(status);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           // BadRequest(ex.InnerException);
            throw ex;

        }
    }
```

Client Method

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Ftp( FileModel file)
    {
        try
        {
            string response = "";
            long totlength = file.MyFile.Length + file.Token.Length + file.userid.Length;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:49834/api/ftp/FileUpload");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data;boundary=gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p";
            
            request.ContentLength = totlength;
            request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + file.Token + "";
            StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
            requestWriter.Write(file);
            requestWriter.Close();
            request.Timeout = 200000;
            WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();
            Stream webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream);
            response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Try to increase the request time or use a small file to test whether the code works well or not. Besides, from your description, it seems that you want to create a FtpWebRequest request, you could refer [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest?view=net-5.0).

Comment: I'm calling this API from jQuery AJAX but CORS error even after Enabled CORS, I don't know this error is truly cause of CORS or is there anything else.

Comment: In your code, you are using try catch statement to catch the exception, can you post the detail exception message? And you could also use F12 developer tools to get the error message.